# remove a component from netbeans swing ui

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-8, swingx, netbeans-plugins

I added some components like button, panel etc. in Netbeans Swing UI in design view. I am not able to delete or remove any of components of my choice in design view. Please note that I am not willing to remove or hide any of components during run time. I want to remove components during design time itself. What should I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to right click on the component, and click on 'Delete' in the list that appears. If 'Delete' does not appear, I recommend restarting NetBeans. If that does not work, and this is probably overkill, you could reinstall NetBeans however it shouldn't come to this.